# Shared stores on multi applications Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

I build multi-app Nuxt project, those apps don't communicate directly between them.
Each app has own store and I want to use a directory for shared stores. I use this approach with components and that works fine.

```
|-> app1
|   |-> store // store app1
|   |   |-> moduleapp1.js
|   |-> components // component app1
|   |-> nuxt.config.js
|
|-> app2
|   |-> store // store app2
|   |   |-> moduleapp2.js
|   |-> components // component app2
|   |-> nuxt.config.js
|
|-> store // shared stores for all app
|   |-> shared_module_1.js
|   |-> shared_module_2.js
|-> components // components for all app, that works fine
```

Each app has a nuxt.config.js almost similar :

```
export default {
  srcDir: __dirname,
  buildDir: '.nuxt/app1',
  dir: {
    static: '../static/', //shared static
    assets: '../assets/', //shared assets
    //store: allow only a string, not Array 
  },
  plugins: [
    '../plugins/plugin_1', //own plugin
    './plugins/plugin_2', //shared plugin
  ],
  components: [
    '../components', //shared components
    {
      path: '../components/grid/', //shared components
      ignore: './filter/*.vue' //shared components

    },
    {path: './components/modal/', prefix: 'Modal'}, //own component
    {path: './components/nav/', prefix: 'Nav'}, //own component
  ]
}
```

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-dir

Each app uses own and shared components also plugins and that works fine.
But I don't find how I can do that with store, is it possible ?

Comment: Hm, I may be wrong but this **seems** impossible to me.

Comment: Thanks, but with components this conception works fine.

Comment: Being outside of the project is a totally whole different thing aka, exporting your state outside of your codebase and importing it somewhere else. It's not like it's some plain text, but some dynamic runtime values. So yeah, not the same scope at all.

Comment: But I'm maybe wrong. I guess that an example of what you already did could maybe prove that I'm wrong. Do you have a [repro]?

Comment: One solution could be using the only store directory and set `dir:{store: '../store'}` and put in all modules in this directory. That will works, but all apps'll load modules which they never use. Not perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use plugin is the solution, like that :

```js
// plugin/loadStore.js
// - List of shared stores
import Grid from '../store/grid';
import Map from '../store/map';
import Sidebar from '../store/sidebar';

export default ({isClient, store}) => {

  const opts = {}
  if (isClient) {
    opts.preserveState = true;
  }

  store.registerModule('grid', Grid, opts);
  store.registerModule('map', Map, opts);
  store.registerModule('sidebar', Sidebar, opts);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for a solution.